# Magento - Add phtml file to layout block

Tags: magento

I am trying to add some code that will display text directly below the product's price on the product page - further, Im trying to do this the 'Magento' way by not just copying the code into view.phtml, but by creating at block, and then referencing that block in a layout file.

For better or worse, I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/).

So far I have created the phtml file that contains what I want to display (sharethis.phtml)
Created a reference in page xml:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="sharethis" as="sharethis"/>
```

just after this block

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
<label>Left Column</label>
</block>
```

Referenced that reference in catalog.xml, just after the first default tag:

```
    <reference name="sharethis">
        <block type="catalog/product_new" name="sharethis" template="catalog/product/view/sharethis.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

And finally called that block from the view.phtml file like so

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharethis') ?>
```

But its not showing up.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to add a structural block? or just a block underneath the price? as they are different. If i understand what your trying to do in catalog.xml (layout file) add:

```
<catalog_product_view>
   ...
   <reference name="content">
       <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
        <!--- ADD THIS -->
           <block type="catalog/product_new" name="sharethis" template="catalog/product/view/sharethis.phtml"/>
        <!-- END ADD -->
       ...
       </block>
    ...
    </reference>
    ...
</catalog_product_view>
```

Basically to echo a child block the said block has to be a child of the block your in.

Also your type might be wrong, make sure you are using the correct type.

Comment: the place that you put your block depends on where exactly you are trying to have the block show up. ... so if that doesn't work I would need to know what block exactly you were trying to put the "sharethis" block in

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have 2 blocks with the same name (here it's what you'll get, since you're declaring 2 blocks "sharethis")