# Adding a block to magento category page using local.xml

Tags: magento

Before posting this, i have looked in to the following, but all of them did not helped me and i was not able to add the block.

[magento - adding and positioning a block using local.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777278/magento-adding-and-positioning-a-block-using-local-xml)

[Magento - Add phtml file to layout block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805598/magento-add-phtml-file-to-layout-block)

[Magento 1.7:Show category image on category page in full width in a 2 column template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186458/magento-1-7show-category-image-on-category-page-in-full-width-in-a-2-column-tem)

I want to add the category image on top of the page. Currently it is displayed under the product list view, and i want it to be above the left navigation, so that it takes full page width.

I created a template file in **mytheme/template/catalog/category/image.phtml**  and i just added some text "I am here".

After that i add the following xml to my local.xml file under **catalog_category_default**

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.image" template="catalog/category/image.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

But it is still not working and the text is not displayed there. When this text is displayed, then i will display the category image, but for now i just want to make the block working and display it on top of the page.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your category does not load the layout handle `catalog_category_default`. There are 2 handles for categories `_default` and `_layered`.
To make sure you cover both cases and so you won't duplicate markup try this approach.
define your custom handle.

```
<my_awsome_category_handle>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.image" template="catalog/category/image.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</my_awsome_category_handle>
```

Then include that handle in both category handles.

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <update handle="my_awsome_category_handle" />
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <update handle="my_awsome_category_handle" />
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me. Sorry for late acceptance :) .